# In app purchase?

Tags: android

can anyone please tell me how to get list of products available for purchase?I am using trivial drive example for reference.suppose on developer console in my app i listed  two products as product1 & product 2.How to get list of available products in my app.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be what you're looking for:

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#QueryDetails

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    IabHelper billingHelper = new IabHelper(this, AppPublicKey.BASE_64_KEY);

                billingHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                            // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                            complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                            return;
                        }

                        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
                        if (billingHelper == null) return;
                        List<String> aListSKU = new ArrayList<String>();
                        aListSKU.add(ProductId.SKU100);
                        aListSKU.add(ProductId.SKU200);
                        aListSKU.add(ProductId.SKU400);
                        billingHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, aListSKU, mGotInventoryListener);
                    }
                });
```

Create QueryInventoryFinishedListener  Interface

```
            // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own


    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

                     // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
                   if (billingHelper == null) return;

                   // Is it a failure?
                   if (result.isFailure()) {
                       Toast.makeText(ProfileCreditActivity.this, "Failed to query inventory: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       return;
                   }

                   Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

                   SkuDetails sku100Details = inventory.getSkuDetails(ProductId.SKU100);
                   sku100Price = sku100Details.getPrice();
                   sku100Title = sku100Details.getTitle();

                   SkuDetails sku200Details = inventory.getSkuDetails(ProductId.SKU200);
                   sku200Price = sku200Details.getPrice();
                   sku200Title = sku100Details.getTitle();

                   SkuDetails sku400Details = inventory.getSkuDetails(ProductId.SKU400);
                   sku400Price = sku400Details.getPrice();
                   sku400Title = sku100Details.getTitle();



                    updateUI();
                }

            };
```

Update your UI here

```
private void updateUI() {

    }
```